# Image manipulation with javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I need the best way to manipulate with image in web browser with javascript. How create script which will change brightness or contrast. I google a little but i can find any acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your audience have modern browsers you can use the `<canvas>` tag.

Here is a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 6):

Check [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/).
It is very flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at library:
http://www.pixastic.com/

Comment: Note that this depends on a modern browser that supports the <canvas> tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with javascript.  You need to use GDLib or some other server side image manipulation library.

Comment: That's not correct actually, there is a lot of jquery plugins that allow you to manipulate images. In fact there is simple photo editors in jquery

Comment: It is possible. You can manipulate images easily using canvas element. Though it's not cross browser solution. But you can work around even that using iecanvas.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, pretty  cool.  Too bad it doesn't work with IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best option here is to use something like flash, java, etc.  JavaScript MIGHT be able to do this, but it will never be able to do it WELL.  It is better to use a technology that has the power to do what you are asking without being stretched to it's limit.