# How to change the tint of background image using CSS3?

Tags: css

Is it possible to change the color or tint of background image on hover/focus using pure css

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/HdDRA/

In above example there is a white arrow on an image. I want to change the color of white arrow ( not the other background image) to something else on hover and focus.

I cannot use inline images in my case.

**Edit:**

I'm looking almost same like this http://jsbin.com/icemiy but for background images.

And I also want to change the color with fade-out so I can't do with multiple images

Comment: What about changing the arrow image with another one with the desired color ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty fix would be to duplicate the arrow image in the color you want it to be onHover. Then replace the background image with this in the code.

```
body 
{
    background: 
        url(http://www.kapellohair.com/images/white-arrow.png) no-repeat,
        url(http://www.tnpsc.com/downloads/NaturesScenery.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position:
        center 50px, 
        center top;
}

body:hover
{
    background: 
        url(http://www.example.com/images/arrow-with-desired-color.png) no-repeat,
        url(http://www.tnpsc.com/downloads/NaturesScenery.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position:
        center 50px, 
        center top;
}
```

p.s: The link does not exist. It is only for illustration purposes

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do what you want, you can change the background using another *different* image.

An alternative could be to use a font to render the arrow and then to change its color (which is also animatable).

Alternatively, you can rely on Javascript to do some color manipulations on the image. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210861/799073)

Comment: the link you give is for  inline images not background

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking off the top of my head here.

I suppose you could put a transparent coloured div over the top of the image with an opacity of 0, then have its opacity go up to say 10% on hover.  You'd be somewhat limited on what you could do though, it would look weird if you did it to an image with an irregular outline, for example, and you'd only have limited control over the tinting (I think it would pretty much be the equivalent of a semi-opaque layer in Photoshop so you couldn't do anything that you would require other tricks such as multiply or screen to achieve).